# The existence of continuous real-valued functions

Tags: general-topology

> Show that there exists a continuous real-valued function $h$ on $[0,1]$ such that
> $$ \lim _{t\to0+}\sup\left|\frac{h(x+t)-h(x)}{t}\right|=\infty$$
> whenever $0\leq x < 1$.

$\textit{Hint:}$ Consider the space $C([0, 2])$ of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0, 2]$, with the metric of uniform convergence. Let $E_m$ be the set of $f\in C([0,2])$ for which there exists $x\in[0,1]$ satisfying $|f(x+t)-f(x)|/|t| \leq m$ for $t>0, x+t\leq 2$. Show that $E_m$ is a closed nowhere-dense susbset of $C([0,2])$.

I am stuck with this problem. I cannot find (1) why $E_m$ is closed nowhere-dense subset of $C[0, 2]$, and (2) if (1) is true, how I can get to the final answer.

For (2) I knowt that $E_m^c$ is a dense open subset. By Baire Category Theorem, $\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}\{E_m\}$ is also dense in $C[0, 2]$. But this is it. I cannot go further. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer.

Let $(f_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence in $E_m$ converging uniformly to $f$. Suppose $f\not \in E_m.$ For each $n\in \Bbb N$ let $x_n\in [0,1]$ such that $\forall y\in (x_n,2]\, (|f(y)-f(x_n)|\le m|y-x_n|).$ Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ such that $(x_n)_{n\in S}$ converges to $x.$

Obviously $x\in [0,1].$ Since $f\not \in E_m$ there exists $y\in (x,2]$ with $|f(y)-f(x)|=m'|y-x|$ with $m'>m.$

Now  we have $$ (\bullet) \quad |f_n(y)-f_n(x_n)|=$$ $$=|(f(y)-f(x))+(f_n(y)-f(y))+(f(x_n)-f_n(x_n))+(f(x)-f(x_n))|\ge$$ $$\ge  |f(y)-f(x)|-|f_n(y)-f(y)|-|f(x_n)-f_n(x_n)|-|f(x)-f(x_n)|.$$ But if $n\in S$ is large enough that (i) $x_n<y$ and (ii) $\sup \{|f(z)-f_n(z)|: z\in [0,2]\}< \frac {1}{4}(m'-m)|y-x|$ and (iii) $ |f(x)-f(x_n)|<\frac {1}{4}(m'-m)|y-x|$ then in $(\bullet)$  we have $|f_n(y)-f_n(x_n)|> (m'-\frac{3}{4}(m'-m))|y-x_n|>m|y-x|,$ a contradiction.

So, by contradiction, $E_m$ is closed.